# Effect of Scoping/hoisting on variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading a tutorial on Javascript basics & how it is different from other languages like C, C++ in terms of having **function-level** scope rather than **block-level scope**, but, came across this script which got me confused!

So, Basically:

1. I want to know how does outcome of the following code comes to be
       '1'?
2. And exactly what is the role of function a() {} ? I mean its never called and in `function b() {}` also there's a return statement before its declaration. But if i change the function name , the alert gives the value '10'.Why?

   ```
   <script>
       var a = 1;

       function b() {  
           a = 10;
           return;
           function a() {}
       }

       b();
       alert(a);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: @Sarath I have still one doubt remaining why the functional decalaration " function a() {} " is being parsed into functional expressions "var a= function a() {} "

Comment: The difference is that `var a= function() {}` is defined at run-time, whereas `function a() {}` is defined at parse-time ., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname